# Division/Department/Section

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, usage

What is the difference among "division", "department" and "section" ?

> Human Resources(HR) Division, HR Department and HR Section are all equally often used in western countries and all of them has same meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[section](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/section) is one of the parts that something is divided into

[department](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/department) is a part of an organization such as a school, business, or government that deals with a particular area of study or work

So, these two both mean a part, but department clarifies that it is part of an organization.

[division](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/division) means a separate part of an army or large organization

Note the word **separate** there.

The term **Human Resources Division** can have the same meaning as department or section, but it is more often used about a separate part of a group of companies: for example [PA Consulting Group](http://www.paconsulting.com/) has a number of separate business units or divisions that offer consultancy services in a particular area- **Human Resources Division**, **Technology division**, **Supply Chain Division**. Within each division, there is probably a Human resources department or section that services the HR needs of that division.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, generally, division is supposed to be larger than department? I mean, HR Department could be inside HR Division, but vice versa is impossible?

Comment: Size is a factor, but the separateness is the most important thing.